# MySQL: does indices needed on both fields of table that are joined?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

When I execute a SQL like this;

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_foo 
  JOIN table_bar
    ON table_foo.foo_id = table_bar.bar_id
```

do I need an index just on `table_foo.foo_id` ?

Or does MySQL uses both indices on `table_foo.foo_id` and `table_bar.bar_id` ?

The result of `EXPLAIN` is like this.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add the index on table_foo and see if MySQL likes it.

Comment: you need  both ..

Comment: Salman A, of course, but the two tables are actually big (millions of rows) and it takes times to add indices. So I want to make sure what indices I need.

Comment: What does "need" mean? You don't need indexes to query. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @Taichi the answer is "it depends". I am sure your actual query will have a WHERE clause and perhaps an ORDER BY, and SELECT a, b, c instead if SELECT \*. All of these matter when creating an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possible execution plans for this query:

```
SELECT f.*, b.* 
FROM table_foo f JOIN
     table_bar b
     ON f.foo_id = b.bar_id;
```

Here are some examples:

1. The one you want to avoid (presumably) is a nested loop join that loops through one table -- row by row -- and then for each row loops through the second one.
2. Scan `foo` and look up each value in `bar`, using an index on `table_bar(bar_id)`.  From the row id in the `bar` index, get the associated columns for each matching row.
3. Scan `bar` and look up each value in `foo`, using an index on `table_foo(foo_id)`.  From the row id in the `foo` index, get the associated columns for each matching row.
4. Scan *both* indexes using a merge join and look up the associated rows in each of the tables.

This leave out other options such as hash join which would not normally use indexes.

So, either or both indexes might be used, depending on which algorithms the optimizer implements.  That is, one index is often going to be good enough to get the performance you want.  But, you give the optimizer more options if you have an index on both tables.